# for each publish,how can i make my device name as unique?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, publish, nsnetservice

i am publishing my netService object once with same domain and name.
 another device finding my service as **myService** .

but again i  publishing my netService object again with same domain and name .another device will detect my devise as **myService(1)**.

code:

```
self.netService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:domain type:protocol name:name port:self.port];
if(self.netService == nil)
    return NO;

[self.netService scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
****[self.netService publish];****
[self.netService setDelegate:self];
```

for each publish,how can i make  my device name as unique?

Answer (score 1):

You can use unique Device Id for this:

```
NSString* deviceID = [ UIDevice currentDevice ].uniqueIdentifier;
```